# How to avoid duplication insertion in MongoDB when multiple instances of Tornado app is inserting item in database?

Tags: jquery, python, mongodb, nginx, tornado

I have built a simple wish list app in Tornado. The user adds URL to the product and the app keeps tracking its price. The flow is simple, the user logs in, there is a form and user pastes/enters the url in the form and clicks submit. This makes a post request to my server and that url will be added to database.

For submit I am using ajax. So, it submits the request and refreshes the wishlist table in the page. However as this takes time, the users think the app is not working and tend to press 'submit' multiple times. It takes time, as my server verifies the URL, fetches its price, image and other details.

During initial stages, I was talking directly to Tornado server. When I press submit button multiple times, Tornado would add it only once. I don't know how it managed to ignore same requests or how it figured out its same request, which is being processed. Since it never occurred, I never thought about it.

Now there are four instances of Tornado are running behind a Nginx server. So I guess Nginx is passing the request to different tornado instances when multiple times submit is pressed.

So how do I avoid this?

- I could create a local storage in browser for every session and maintain list of URLs. When submit is pressed and if URL is already present in the list, then don't send the request. And I would destroy this storage whenever tab is closed.
- disable submit button once the url is submitted and till it receives reply from the server
- give a facebook style notification when the submit is pressed and hope user does not press submit again.
- configure nginx load balancer to work on ip-hash mode. so that the user always gets to served by same instance of Tornado
- may be configure nginx somehow that it ignores same POST requests as single instance of Tornado was doing earlier?

Here's the code in question (not sure if it actually matters):

```
class ProductsHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        # ...
        # ...

    def post(self):
        user_email = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
        user_db = self.application.db.users
        product_db = self.application.db.products
        product_url = self.get_argument('product-url', None)
        if not product_url:
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        vendor, url = utils.get_vendor(product_url)

        if not vendor:
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        # this is where it checks whether the URL is already present in DB or not
        product_doc = product_db.find_one({'url': url})

        if not product_doc:
            # ...
            # ...            
            product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = vendor_func_map[vendor_id](url)

            product_id = str(product_db.insert({'vendor_name': vendor_name,
                'vendor_id': vendor_id, 
                'name': product_name, 'url': url,
                'img_url': upload_to_imgur(product_img_url), 
                'price': product_price
                # ...
                # ...
                }))
        else:
            product_id = product_doc['_id']

        # add this product to users db
        # ...
        self.redirect('/products')
```

and jquery code for ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#product-add-form").on('submit',function(){
            var product_url = $("#product-url").val();
            console.log(product_url)
            var dataString = 'product-url='+ product_url
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "products",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('#product-table-div').load("/products #product-table-div")
                }
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The HTML form:

```
<div id="product-add">
    <form action="/products" method="post" id="product-add-form">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="product-url">Product-Url</label>
            <input class="text-input" id="product-url" name="product-url" tabindex="1" type="text" value="">
        </fieldset>
        <div id="form_btn">
            <input id="prodadd-btn" class="btn btn-blue" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="3">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as I said on the Tornado mailing list: I see you're using PyMongo with Tornado. I can't recommend this approach since a long-running MongoDB operation will block an entire Tornado process from all work. (I maintain Motor, a non-blocking MongoDB driver for Tornado.) But PyMongo does have the advantage of avoiding race conditions.

In your code you query for the product, and if it's absent you insert it. This worked well with a single Tornado process because it handled one request at a time, and it couldn't be interrupted between querying and inserting. If it finds no document, there's still no document a moment later when it attempts to do the insert.

With multiple Tornado processes, however, a user can press the button twice quickly, and something like this happens:

1. Process A queries, finds no product.
2. Process B queries, finds no product.
3. Process A inserts a document.
4. Process B inserts a duplicate document.

I would:

- Disable the "submit" button before beginning the AJAX POST. Make sure you show a spinner, and re-enable the button after a timeout or HTTP 500 or other error.
- Create a unique compound index on the fields in the products collection that ought to be unique.
- Decide how your python code is going to handle pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError should one occur. (Raising an informative error to the user might be fine.)

Comment: Is there a reason for not using optimistic locking?

Comment: Optimistic locking is good for *updates*. It works when you first know which record you want to update, then you read it, and then update it. In Avi's case he wants to insert a new document and he doesn't know in advance what its unique fields' values will be. A simple unique index will work fine for him.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be to use `update` with `upsert` flag, which is **insert if not found**.
In this case, it will not make duplicates.

```
update({
    "product_url": url
}, {
    'vendor_name': vendor_name,
    'vendor_id': vendor_id, 
    'name': product_name, 'url': url,
    'img_url': upload_to_imgur(product_img_url), 
    'price': product_price
}, upsert=True)
```

**But**, it is not what you should do. Before adding product url, you should make a check **is this url already added in db?**, so you should notify user "this url already added".

**But**, your problem is, you should **lock** ability to make new request in this case. So, make a variable "inProgress" somewhere and check it. On button press, check is it `true`. If it is `true`, warn user about it. Otherwise make it `true` and go on your request.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @A. Jesse Jiryu Davis advice and here are the changes I made.

First I created a unique single index (I don't need compounded one, as `_id` is already indexed and I just wanted only `url` field in `product` document to be unique)

```
product_db.create_index('url', unique=True, dropDups=True)
```

Do note that above one will remove all the duplicate documents which have same `url`. If you don't want that, then do following:

```
product_db.create_index('url', unique=True)
```

If there are any duplicate keys exists, then PyMongo will throw `DuplicateKeyError` exception.

I changed my javascript code, now at start of ajax it disables the submit button and re-enables it later:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $("#product-add-form").on('submit',function()
        {    
            var product_url = $("#product-url").val();
            console.log(product_url)
            var dataString = 'product-url='+ product_url
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "products",
              data: dataString,
              success: function() {
                $('#product-table-div').load("/products #product-table-div")
              }
            });
            return false;
        });        
    })
    .ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#prodadd-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        NProgress.start(); 
    })
    .ajaxStop(function(){
        $("#prodadd-btn").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        NProgress.done();
    });
```

I also used [Nprogress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) to show a cool progress bar.

These changes should be sufficient to prevent user entering same url multiple times. However there is a possibility that two users could enter same url at the same time. Now as I have created a unique single index, the second insertion will throw `DuplicateKeyError`. In that case I will just find that url by from db and add it to user. Here is the modified code:

```
def post(self):
    user_email = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
    user_db = self.application.db.users
    product_db = self.application.db.products
    tracker_db = self.application.db.trackers # this has product_id to users_id
    product_url = self.get_argument('product-url', None)

    # ...

    product_doc = product_db.find_one({'url': url})
    if not product_doc:
        # ...
        # ...            
        product_url, product_name, product_img_url, product_price = vendor_func_map[vendor_id](url)

        try:
            product_id = str(product_db.insert({
            # ...
            'url': url,
            'current_price': product_price,
            }))                
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            product_doc = product_db.find_one({'url': url})
            product_id = product_doc['_id']
    else:
        product_id = product_doc['_id']

    user_db.update({'email_id': user_email}, {'$addToSet': {'tracked_products': ObjectId(product_id)}})
    # ...
    self.redirect('/products')
```